# BigVideo.js Uncaught ReferenceError: _V_ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this error when i try to use BigVideo.js (http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _V_ is not defined
```

This error comes up right after this line

```
player = _V_(vidEl.substr(1), { 'controls': false, 'autoplay': true, 'preload': 'auto' });
```

I'm running ruby on rails and this is the script I used to load BigVideo

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var BV = new $.BigVideo();
 BV.init();
 BV.show('http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4');
  });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a dependencies issue to me.
Check if video.js is correctly included in your document, as well as imagesloaded and jquery ui.